# Drive API: when exporting a spreadsheet the mimetype has to be excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

[image: return;]

I am trying to understand how Drive API works and come acorss this page: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%221OtlQNu7cKelnXBJk2gdCXHJkT0ixNugXfaBkQfQzxto%22%2C%22mimeType%22%3A%22application%2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet%22%7D

I have done some tests on the sidebar and this is the Google Sheet file I use to test:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OtlQNu7cKelnXBJk2gdCXHJkT0ixNugXfaBkQfQzxto/edit#gid=1722278454

You can see on both screenshots I input the fileId and mimeType. To my surprise, when the mimeType is set to "google sheet", it will return an error; and if I change the mimeType to MS excel, it will return 200.

Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Answer to

> Drive API: when exporting a spreadsheet the mimeType has to be excel?

In the current stage, Google Docs (Document, Spreadsheet, Slide, Form) cannot be exported as the original mimeType. In that case, it is required to convert the mimeType. For example, in the case of a Spreadsheet, it can be exported as the following mimeTypes.

```
"application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet"
"text/tab-separated-values"
"application/pdf"
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
"text/csv"
"application/zip"
"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet"
```

You can see these values at ["About: get"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get?apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22exportFormats%22%7D). In this case, `exportFormats` is put into `fields`. When you see this, you can also see about the other Google Docs.

From the above export mimeTypes, an answer to `Drive API: when exporting a spreadsheet the mimeType has to be excel?` is as follows.

- No. You can export Google Spreadsheet by selecting the exporting mimeType (the above mimeTypes), while Google Spreadsheet cannot be exported as Google Spreadsheet by the current specification.

#### 2. Answer to

> To my surprise, when the mimeType is set to "google sheet", it will return an error; and if I change the mimeType to MS excel, it will return 200. Why is this?

About `when the mimeType is set to "google sheet", it will return an error`, the mimeType of Spreadsheet is `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`. But, when `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` is used as the exported mimeType, an error like `The requested conversion is not supported.` occurs because of the above reason. Please be careful about this.

Also, you can see "Google Workspace & Google Drive supported MIME types" at the official document. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/mime-types)

#### References:

- [About: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get)
- [Google Workspace & Google Drive supported MIME types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/mime-types)

Comment: @chris neilsen Thank you for editing it. Using your suggestion of edit, I modified the header of "1. Answer to".

Comment: If the spreadsheet contains image, is excel mimetype the only way to get it?

Comment: @shenkwen Thank you for replying. About `If the spreadsheet contains image, is excel mimetype the only way to get it?`, in this case, I think that `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` and `application/zip` can be used. In the case of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`, you can retrieve the images from XLSX data. In the case of `application/zip`, you can retrieve the images by unzipping it.

Comment: Thanks. In my App Script, I have been able to get the sheet as an excel blob, I believe this blob is the "XLSX daa" you mentioned. But how do I "retrieve the images" from it?

Comment: @shenkwen Thank you for replying. About `In my App Script, I have been able to get the sheet as an excel blob, I believe this blob is the "XLSX daa" you mentioned. But how do I "retrieve the images" from it?`, XLSX data is a zip file. So, you can retrieve the images by unzipping it. If you want more information about your new question, these threads might be useful. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+XLSX+extract+images)